# Field restTemplate required a single bean, but 2 were found

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-security, resttemplate, spring-hateoas

I am trying to resolve an issue with this code:

```
import io.christdoes.wealth.tracker.controller.error.ReCaptchaInvalidException;
import io.christdoes.wealth.tracker.controller.error.ReCaptchaUnavailableException;
import org.slf4j.Logger;
import org.slf4j.LoggerFactory;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Service;
import org.springframework.util.StringUtils;
import org.springframework.web.client.RestClientException;
import org.springframework.web.client.RestOperations;
import org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate;

import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import java.net.URI;
import java.util.regex.Pattern;

@Service("captchaService")
public class CaptchaService implements ICaptchaService {
    private final static Logger LOGGER = LoggerFactory.getLogger(CaptchaService.class);

    @Autowired
    private HttpServletRequest request;

    @Autowired
    private CaptchaSettings captchaSettings;

    @Autowired
    private ReCaptchaAttemptService reCaptchaAttemptService;

    @Autowired
    private RestOperations restTemplate;

    private static final Pattern RESPONSE_PATTERN = Pattern.compile("[A-Za-z0-9_-]+");

    @Override
    public void processResponse(final String response) {
        LOGGER.debug("Attempting to validate response {}", response);

        if (reCaptchaAttemptService.isBlocked(getClientIP())) {
            throw new ReCaptchaInvalidException("Client exceeded maximum number of failed attempts");
        }

        if (!responseSanityCheck(response)) {
            throw new ReCaptchaInvalidException("Response contains invalid characters");
        }

        final URI verifyUri = URI.create(String.format("https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api/siteverify?secret=%s&response=%s&remoteip=%s", getReCaptchaSecret(), response, getClientIP()));
        try {
            final GoogleResponse googleResponse = restTemplate.getForObject(verifyUri, GoogleResponse.class);
            LOGGER.debug("Google's response: {} ", googleResponse.toString());

            if (!googleResponse.isSuccess()) {
                if (googleResponse.hasClientError()) {
                    reCaptchaAttemptService.reCaptchaFailed(getClientIP());
                }
                throw new ReCaptchaInvalidException("reCaptcha was not successfully validated");
            }
        } catch (RestClientException rce) {
            throw new ReCaptchaUnavailableException("Registration unavailable at this time.  Please try again later.", rce);
        }
        reCaptchaAttemptService.reCaptchaSucceeded(getClientIP());
    }

    private boolean responseSanityCheck(final String response) {
        return StringUtils.hasLength(response) && RESPONSE_PATTERN.matcher(response).matches();
    }

    @Override
    public String getReCaptchaSite() {
        return captchaSettings.getSite();
    }

    @Override
    public String getReCaptchaSecret() {
        return captchaSettings.getSecret();
    }

    private String getClientIP() {
        final String xfHeader = request.getHeader("X-Forwarded-For");
        if (xfHeader == null) {
            return request.getRemoteAddr();
        }
        return xfHeader.split(",")[0];
    }
}
```

Error

```
web - 2019-09-25 14:20:18,416 [restartedMain] INFO  o.a.c.c.StandardService - Stopping service [Tomcat]
web - 2019-09-25 14:20:18,491 [restartedMain] ERROR o.s.b.d.LoggingFailureAnalysisReporter - 

***************************
APPLICATION FAILED TO START
***************************

Description:

Field restTemplate in io.christdoes.wealth.tracker.captcha.CaptchaService required a single bean, but 2 were found:
    - org.springframework.hateoas.config.ConverterRegisteringWebMvcConfigurer#0: defined in null
    - org.springframework.hateoas.config.ConverterRegisteringWebMvcConfigurer#1: defined in null


Action:

Consider marking one of the beans as @Primary, updating the consumer to accept multiple beans, or using @Qualifier to identify the bean that should be consumed


Process finished with exit code 0
```

I have been trying to resolve this issue and could not find a way to resolve it. I kept on getting the above error.

I have searched both SO and Github where similar errors were reported but non helped. Someone noted that it's a dependency issue, that's having both spring-web, and hateoas could be the issue. I removed the web yet the problem persists.

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-hateoas</artifactId>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
</dependency>
```

Though an earlier project with spring-boot dependencies of version `2.0.4` worked, I am presently using the latest version which is `2.1.8`. I will not like to revert to the earlier version because I have recent codes that I solely used `2.1.8`.

What am I to do to get past this challenge?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can check one of those method :

1. **The first** :

   is to remove the `spring boot` , because it's a hierarchic dependency of 
   `spring-boot-starter-hateoas`

   in which I think this cause twice creation of the bean

   ```
   <dependency>
       <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
       <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
   </dependency>
   ```

   then clean , and reinstall your project . run again .
2. **Second Solution** :

   create your own RestTemplate bean , since this last implement the [RestOperations](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/client/RestOperations.html) interface : 
   and use it as folow :

   In a config class create a bean :

   ```
   @Bean
   public RestTemplate myRestTemplate(RestTemplateBuilder builder) {

       return builder
                .setConnectTimeout(10000)
                .setReadTimeout(10000)
                .build();
   }
   ```

   then replace the autowired

   ```
   @Autowired
   private RestOperations restTemplate;
   ```

   by :

   ```
   @Autowired
   private RestTemplate myRestTemplate;
   ```

Comment: I’m very grateful for this. I’m presently on Mobile phone, I’ll do the needful once on my system.

Comment: Thanks @Springer F, I have done as noted here but it's still the same. I'll try and purge the entire local maven cache and reinstall afresh.

Comment: hi @kehinde , the error thrown also after using the second method ?

Comment: It’s still the same error. It’s like pulling my hairs off right now as this stuff has refused to go for over a day. I’ve tried all the suggestions. I deleted the local Maven cache / repository and reran the project the same thing persists. I’m thinking maybe there could be some dependencies that are still causing the problem. Now I’m reviewing it. Could any of these be the cause as well? I have these 3 in the POM file: spring data-jpa, data-rest-core, data-rest-mvc. I’m of the opinion that only one should be needed among the 3, if so, please which should I retain and remove others?

Comment: try remove   data-rest-core and  data-rest-core spring-hateoas and bring back spring boot ?

Comment: Thanks. I have done all of these. None worked. Please, any more suggestions

Answer (score 0):

I solved the problem by using RestTemplateBuilder instead of RestTemplate.
Before I removed my @Bean RestTemplate creation from configuration file.

```
 private RestTemplate restTemplate;
   public MyClass(RestTemplateBuilder restTemplate){
     this.restTemplate = restTemplate.build();
    }
```